# git format-patch return empty reponse on feature branch

Tags: git, format-patch

We have branch structure - master - develop - feature.
We created feature from develop and made few changes in the branch. We don't want to merge all changes from branch . Therefore , trying to create the patch.

When i run **git format-patch feature/branch-name** , it returns **empty response**. But, when i run **git format-patch origin** , it returns the **list of files missing between develop and master**.

I am not sure **why git format-patch will return empty response for branch**?

Comment: `git format-patch` takes the name of the base-branch as the argument. So if you're currently on `feature/branch-name` and execute `git format-patch feature/branch-name` then you're asking for the difference between `feature/branch-name` and `feature/branch-name`, which will be empty. Instead you should execute `git format-patch develop` if you want to know the difference to develop. Note that rebasing and cherry-picking might provide a more integrated workflow for what you're trying to achieve (i.e. doesn't need to take the de-tour of having external patch files), but it's a little unclear.

Comment: I tried git format-patch develop as well. It would return empty response. What i am trying to achieve here is create patch for all the changes that are in feature and not in develop . Once, i have patch i will delete the branch. 
But , format-patch is not returning me correct results. Either my understanding is incorrect or i am skipping a step. When i do git format-patch develop , it should return patch files (containing the difference of commits)

Answer (score 0):

> What I am trying to achieve here is create patch for all the changes that are in `feature` and not in `develop`.

That should be:

```bash
git switch feature
git format-patch develop --stdout > feature_patches.patch
```

A simple `git format-patch develop` would create separate patch files for each commit.

But in that latter case, you might want to use the new `--omit-empty` option.

With Git 2.41 (Q2 2023), "[`git branch --format=...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b64894c2063e5875bfd95b537eafcb3e1abf46ff/Documentation/git-branch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch))</sup> and [`git format-patch --format=...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b64894c2063e5875bfd95b537eafcb3e1abf46ff/Documentation/git-format-patch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch))</sup>  learns `--omit-empty` to hide refs that whose formatting result becomes an empty string from the output.

See [commit aabfdc9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aabfdc9514a51d8d9a2f3afbc29e5044ccf7191b) (07 Apr 2023) by [Øystein Walle (`Osse`)](https://github.com/Osse).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit b64894c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b64894c2063e5875bfd95b537eafcb3e1abf46ff), 21 Apr 2023)</sup>

> ### [`branch, for-each-ref, tag`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aabfdc9514a51d8d9a2f3afbc29e5044ccf7191b): add option to omit empty lines
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Øystein Walle</sup>

> If the given format string expands to the empty string, a newline is still printed.
> This makes using the output linewise more tedious.
> For example, [`git update-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aabfdc9514a51d8d9a2f3afbc29e5044ccf7191b/Documentation/git-update-ref.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-ref))</sup> `--stdin` does not accept empty lines.
>
> Add options to "[`git branch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aabfdc9514a51d8d9a2f3afbc29e5044ccf7191b/Documentation/git-branch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch))</sup>, "[`git for-each-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aabfdc9514a51d8d9a2f3afbc29e5044ccf7191b/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref))</sup>, and "[`git tag`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aabfdc9514a51d8d9a2f3afbc29e5044ccf7191b/Documentation/git-tag.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag))</sup> to not print these empty lines.
> The default behavior remains the same.

`git branch` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aabfdc9514a51d8d9a2f3afbc29e5044ccf7191b/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L159-L162):

`git for-each-ref` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aabfdc9514a51d8d9a2f3afbc29e5044ccf7191b/Documentation/git-for-each-ref.txt#L96-L99):

`git tag` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aabfdc9514a51d8d9a2f3afbc29e5044ccf7191b/Documentation/git-tag.txt#L134-L137):

> ### `--omit-empty`
>
> Do not print a newline after formatted refs where the format expands
> to the empty string.